# How to uninstall Puddletag - audio tag editor?

Tags: uninstall

Today I was install Puddletag (audio tag editor) via deb pack.
I tested it, but now i would like to uninstall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open up a terminal and type sudo apt-get remove puddletag if you installed it as a deb file using gdebi then open the deb file with gdebi and it will give you the option to re-install or remove it. or you can also look in synaptic to see if it is there if it doesn't show in softare center! hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Open Ubuntu Software Centre (look here for more: [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/addremove-remove.html)) then search for puddletag, and remove it

Comment: I tried, but is not in Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: How did you install deb package? Did you double click on it and install with Software Center or in some other way?

Comment: I downloaded debian package from Puddletag [website](http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/download.html#installing-from-the-debian-package)

Answer (score 0):

Open software center, search for puddletag, and click remove.
Then enter your password when prompted, and will uninstall it. Then close software center.